# The definition of Good Movements

Tags: sap-erp

I am new in SAP ABAP Development.
Can someone explain me what is the right definition of the Good Movements in SAP.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Movements are operations done on the inventory materials, such as Goods Receipt. They are classified by the Movement Type, which is a three digits code. Transaction MIGO lets you to do this goods movements.

You can find information about Good Movements here:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/4d/6df0468bf051b0e10000000a42189c/frameset.htm